# Leaderboard Ranking in MySQL with viewer in middle of resultset

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql, leaderboard

I have a Leaderboard that looks like this:

```
|--------------------------------------|
| userId | allTimePoints | allTimeRank |
|--------------------------------------|
|   ..   |      ...      |      ...    |
|   xx   |    5555555    |       ?     |
|   ..   |      ...      |      ...    |
----------------------------------------
```

Let's assume the table has a million records, and that `allTimePoints` is updated constantly. When a user asks to see the Leaderboard, I'd like to be able to show them their rank, score, as well as their closest competitors. I'd like to achieve the following:

- figure out the rank of each user (sort table by allTimePoints DESC)
- figure out paging offset so that leaderboard viewer is in the middle of reduced resultset
- do it within an acceptable runtime (e.g. create perception of instant response even if hundreds of thousands of other users are also hitting the Leaderboard screen at the same time)

I've started like this and this takes about 0.4sec on my machine when the table has 1mil rows.

```
SET @rowIndex := 0;
SET @rank := 0;
SET @prev := NULL;
SET @userIdPosition := 0;
SELECT
    @rowIndex := @rowIndex+1 AS rowIndex,
    userId,
    @rank := IF(@prev=allTimePoints, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank,
    @prev := allTimePoints AS allTimePoints,
    @userIdPosition := IF(userId=1860, @rowIndex, @userIdPosition) AS requestedOffset
FROM Leaderboard
ORDER BY allTimePoints DESC;
```

Btw, the runtime benefit of this method over using a self-join, is described here (it's much faster): http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-ranking-without-self-join

I keep `rowIndex` and `rank` as separate variables, so that I can calculate the requesting user's paging offset more accurately if there are rank ties (i.e., *n* users have same score).

So far so good, although I fear that if this doesn't reduce to msec runtime, it won't be viable when hundreds of thousands of users run the query simultaneously.

To make matters worse, if I expand this query to work correctly with paging as described above, then runtime increases to 1.5sec

```
SET @rowIndex := 0;
SET @rank := 0;
SET @prev := NULL;
SET @userIdPosition := 0;
SELECT sortedL.userId, sortedL.rank, sortedL.allTimePoints
FROM 
    (SELECT
        @rowIndex := @rowIndex+1 AS rowIndex,
        userId,
        @rank := IF(@prev=allTimePoints, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank,
        @prev := allTimePoints AS allTimePoints,
        @userIdPosition := IF(userId=1860, @rowIndex, @userIdPosition) AS requestedOffset
    FROM Leaderboard
    ORDER BY allTimePoints DESC) AS sortedL
-- simulate paging, as LIMIT doesn't seem to accept variables
WHERE sortedL.rowIndex > sortedL.requestedOffset -15 AND sortedL.rowIndex < sortedL.requestedOffset + 15;
```

This returns 29 users and the requesting user is in the middle, as desired.

If I run this with `EXPLAIN`, I can see that the subquery is using a FILESORT, but the results are not indexed, and hence the outer SELECT is forced to do yet another full scan of the resultset using WHERE (slower than FILESORT).

**Questions (1): how can I optimize this?**

Another idea was to store the ranking in an indexed column: `allTimeRank`. I thought I'd experiment with sorting the table in a procedure on a schedule (say, every 10 min), and then offer very quick access with a simpler SELECT that would utilize the index. I haven't managed to get this to work properly, it doesn't seem to be using the condition in my WHERE clause (the ranking stored in `allTimeRank` is incorrect, and MySQL complains so I have to turn off safe updates to get it to even run)

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
SET @rowIndex := 0;
SET @rank := 0;
SET @prev := NULL;
SET @userIdPosition := 0;
UPDATE Leaderboard L, 
    (SELECT
        @rowIndex := @rowIndex+1 AS rowIndex,
        userId,
        @rank := IF(@prev=allTimePoints, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank,
        @prev := allTimePoints AS allTimePoints,
        @userIdPosition := IF(userId=1860, @rowIndex, @userIdPosition) AS requestedOffset
    FROM Leaderboard
    ORDER BY allTimePoints DESC) AS sortedL
SET L.allTimeRank = sortedL.rank
WHERE sortedL.userId = L.userId;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

**Question (2): how do I make the WHERE condition work.**

This has taken between 2min and 12 sec to run. Not sure why the inconsistency. In any case, this will block UPDATEs from users that are winning points, giving the sense that the app has hung. **Question (3): is there a work around?**

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are not computing Rank correctly.  If there are three players:  Britney(100 pts), Rachel(100 pts), and Susan(75 pts), then Britney and Rachel each have a rank of 1, and Susan should have a rank of 3. Your routine would give Susan a rank of 2.

Second, when players have the same score (and rank) they should display in a consistent order. The order within tied scores/ranks should be the order in which she attained that score.

I would add two columns to the table: `allTimeRank`, and `allTimeRankOrder`. And update in real time every time the points change. Realize that if my score goes from 100 to 125, the only users that need to be reranked are those that had scores from 100-124 -- just the people I jumped over.

Here is a routine to do it. It assumes points always go up, never down. I don't have a million row table to test with, but if you have the right indexes set up I hope it will run pretty fast.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateUserPoints`(IN `puserid` VARCHAR(10), IN `pnewPoints` INT)
BEGIN
SET @currPoints = 0;
SET @currRank = 0;
SET @currRankOrder = 0;

SELECT allTimePoints, allTimeRank, allTimeRankOrder INTO @currPoints, @currRank, @currRankOrder from Leaderboard where userid = puserid;

SET @newRank = 0;
SET @newRankOrder = 0;
SELECT max(allTimeRank), max(allTimeRankOrder)+1 INTO @newRank, @newRankOrder FROM Leaderboard WHERE allTimePoints = pnewPoints;

IF (@newRank IS NULL) THEN 
   SET @newRank = (SELECT min(allTimeRank) from Leaderboard WHERE allTimePoints < pnewPoints);
   SET @newRankOrder = 0;
END IF;

UPDATE Leaderboard
   SET allTimePoints = pnewPoints,
       allTimeRank = @newRank,
       allTimeRankOrder = @newRankOrder
 WHERE userid = puserid;

/* all the people that I was tied with, but ahead in order,
   slide up one in the order */
 UPDATE Leaderboard
    SET allTimeRankOrder = allTimeRankOrder - 1
  WHERE allTimeRank = @currRank
    AND allTimeRankOrder > @currRankOrder;

/* did I jump anyone? Their rank goes down. */
UPDATE Leaderboard
   SET allTimeRank = allTimeRank + 1
 WHERE userid <> puserid
  AND allTimePoints >= @currPoints
  AND allTimePoints < pnewPoints;

 END
```